# Interior of closure of open set path-connected

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on the following task:

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ be open.
Proof or give a counter example:

1. If $U$ is path-connected, then $(\overline{U})^\circ$ is also path-connected.
2. If $(\overline{U})^\circ$ is path-connected, then $U$ is also path-connected.

I have already shown: If $U$ is path-connected, then $(\overline{U})$ is also path-connected. I also know that the interior of a path-connected set do not have to be connected. But when I am looking for counter examples I only can think of closed sets $U$. So I am a little bit stucked.. Thanks for your help! Any suggestion is gretaly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$ U=\Bbb R\cup \{\,z\in\Bbb C: |\operatorname{Re}(z)|>1\,\}$$
and
$$ U=\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But why is the first $U$ open? $\mathbb{R}$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$, isn´t it?